# typeahead.js. How do I capture the suggestions list?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I am using **typeahead.js**. I see no event handler that would let me capture the subset of my dataset suggested by a given query. Is there no way to get the actual subset of rows from my dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `typeahead:rendered` event. It passes all shown items as objects in the `arguments` array. The event is fired immediately after the list of suggestions is shown ...

```js
.on('typeahead:rendered', function() { 
    var array = [], i = 1;
    for (i; i<arguments.length; i++) {
       array.push(arguments[i].value) 
    }
    console.log(array);
});
```

would console out `["Alaska", "Arkansas", "Illinois", "Kansas", "Louisiana"]` if the suggested items in the dropdown is `Alaska, Arkansas, Illinois, Kansas, Louisiana` ...

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/kcjgr2rv/** (bear over with the lacking CSS)